# Javascript Countdown to agenda item object

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a watch face on Pujie that displays a simple countdown to my next agenda item. Already have the part that says "Until (Agenda item name)". Just need to figure out how to show the time until it happens. Want it to appear as "47 min until Meeting with Jeff". For items over an hour, could say "1.5 hrs until Meeting with Jeff".

The tag is provided in Pujie for accessing Upcoming Event Title [com_evnt] and Upcoming Event Object [com_evt_full]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: moment.js and its countdown library is a good place to start with this

Comment: Thank you! Will look into that. The more I’m getting into Pujie, I’m starting to think it’s also just very limited in what I’ll be able to do. But will see what I can figure out!

Comment: So moment.js was a great reference for me, but I’m going to be honest, I have no idea how to implement those functions into an expression to make something like what I’m seeking. Any pointers?

Comment: Also - I can wrap my head around the if then statement of ‘if time is > 60m , then display in hour format’, and I could possibly figure that part out coding wise. I just can’t figure out how to make the correct expression for ‘time until future event’ or ‘moment minus future event time’

Comment: Are you using the countdown library? Moment js on it's own is a bit difficult to do those things

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you use asking... I was looking at their relative time section. I just really don’t know how to implement them though... when I try to use one of the code strings, I get an error saying it doesn’t recognize the variable ‘moment’

Comment: Did you include the library? You using nodejs or html in the browser?

Comment: The documentation says its a "combination of JavaScript and predefined variables" - https://pujieblack.com/documentation/watch-part-designer/automation